# Stream BLOB to MySQL with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Sometimes I have issues with writing blobs to MySQL database. To store blob in database it should be loaded to memory, sometimes my process killed by OOM killer. So I think that streaming could solve my issues, but haven't found any information about possibility of streaming BLOB data to MySQL with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: MySQL is not a FILE system.. For smaller files like storing less then 1 Mb MySQL might be able to outperform the file storage (once i saw a benchmark it was a old one but still) for bigger files then 1 Mb you should really store on the filesystem..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, you're right, but I don't use MySQL as filesystem.

Comment: ok you store a unknown amount of data in a blob column in MySQL atleast that is what i understood from "Stream blob to MySQL" then you use MySQL as a file system more or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm accept Raymond's comment, but I still need solution. And I found it. If you want to stream data to BLOB, you could use this weird hack:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import LONGBLOB
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

Base = declarative_base()


def read_data_from_disk(compressed_report_file: str, stream_chunk: int):
    with open(compressed_report_file, 'rb') as compressed_report:
        compressed_report_data = compressed_report.read(stream_chunk)
        while compressed_report_data:
            yield compressed_report_data
            del compressed_report_data
            compressed_report_data = compressed_report.read(stream_chunk)


class TestData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_data'
    id = sa.Column(sa.BigInteger, nullable=False, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    data = sa.Column(LONGBLOB, nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def save_data(cls, session: Session, file_name: str, stream_chunk: int = 1024 ** 2):
        saved_data = cls(data=b'')
        session.add(saved_data)
        try:
            session.flush()
            saved_data_id = saved_data.id
            for file_data in read_data_from_disk(file_name, stream_chunk):
                session.query(cls).filter(cls.id == saved_data_id).update({
                    cls.data: func.concat(cls.data, file_data)
                }, synchronize_session=False)

        except Exception:
            session.rollback()
            raise

        return saved_data_id


db = sa.create_engine('mysql://login:password@host:3306/database?charset=utf8')
session = Session(bind=db)

TestData.save_data(session=session, file_name='FatFile')
session.commit()
```

I put to database file:

```
AT-MBP-7:Python atolkachev$ ls -l FatFile
-rw-r--r--@ 1 atolkachev  staff  35229330 Mar  8 01:30 FatFile
```

Result in database:

```
mysql> select id, OCTET_LENGTH(data) from test_data;
+----+--------------------+
| id | OCTET_LENGTH(data) |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 |           35229330 |
+----+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```